# Are the Dinobots unintelligent or just very aggressive?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-age-of-extinction, optimus-prime, dinobots

I'm talking about the movie version. In *Transformers 4*, Optimus frees all of the Dinobots from their cages and asks them to help fight against Galvatron. Instead of talking it out or anything, Grimlock up and attacked Optimus right away. Also, none of the Dinobots speaks throughout the whole movie.

Furthermore, after Prime's fight with Grimlock, he appeared to "tame" him like an animal, by riding on top of his dinosaur form.

Does all that add up to them just being more of like animals/lesser or unintelligent transformers? Aren't they supposed to be "Legendary Knights"? Or are they just very aggressive in nature which gives the feeling that they're not intelligent?

Comment: The whole script is unintelligent.

Comment: If I remember it correctly he didn't ask them for their help. More like ordered it. Aside from that the whole script has so many logic errors that it can't be said for sure what was intended to look like what and what not.

Comment: The whole point of Transformers 4 was to squeeze more money out of the franchise.. The plot doesn't even make sense.. Bumblebee's vocal cords are not yet repaired although Optimus' entire arm is back!!! And what about each of the new Autobots? and how does only Drift can transform into 2 different kind of vehicles!!! The entire plot seemed as if made for die hard fans of the series only

Comment: the plot making no sense aside (it makes no sense at all even the cahrs themselves behave completely out of char time and again) the 2 differetn kind of vehicles thing appears not only in teh movies but time and again also in other transformers franchise (for example in the G1 cartoons there was at least 1 (if I'm corect it was exactly 1!) former decepticon turned autobot who had 2 alt forms). So that didn't really seem out of concept for me there

Comment: There were 2 triple changers: Astrotrain and Blitswing ( both Decepticons)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Transformers 4* Dinobots appear to have some degree of intelligence, displayed 4 different times.

1. Grimlock did not immediately eat the first human he saw (corrupt businessman)
2. They followed orders when they weren't being ridden, like when it was implied they were fighting in robot mode on the bridge
3. When they were on the bridge, they formed a "defensive line" to prevent the Artificials from interfering in Prime's fight with Lockdown
4. When Prime cut them loose, he said "The legends live " in an alien language. One would stand to reason he was talking to Grimlock, meaning he understood speech. Why would Prime talk to an animal?

These give me reason to believe the Dinobot/Autobot relationship is similar to *Homo sapiens* and *Homo neanderthalensis*. As in, lack of communication between species so similar but different is mistaken for stupidity.

I wonder if Grimlock thought "This red and blue guy? MORON!"

Comment: good observation and rightly put in answer.. +1. Unfortunately the movie storyline / biography of characters vary largely from the comics or animated versions, sigh.

Comment: The tragedy of rushed screen writing:(

Answer (score 0):

The Dinobots, like the classic incarnation of the characters, are very strong and massive but they have little brains and therefore they are not so intelligent. They are more beast-like and that is expressed by their animals form. Therefore, the answer is that both your installments are correct: the Dinobots are not very intelligent and they are very aggressive by nature.